# pandas `value_counts` on a rolling time window

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a pandas dataframe containing string values and a datetime index, like so:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 
                  [dt(2019, 1, 1), dt(2019, 1, 2), 
                   dt(2019, 1, 3), dt(2019, 1, 4), 
                   dt(2019, 1, 5), dt(2019, 1, 6), 
                   dt(2019, 1, 7)])
```

If I wanted to compute the number of instances that each value occurs over all times, I can simply call:

```py
>>> print(df[0].value_counts())
b    5
c    1
a    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

I'd like to create a rolling window and measure the number of instances of each string on a moving window of say, 2 days. Is there a way to combine `rolling` with `value_counts`, or similar?

Comment: Can you show us what is your expected output /

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is:

```
pd.get_dummies(df[0]).rolling('2D').sum()
```

Output:

```
            a   b   c
2019-01-01  1.0 0.0 0.0
2019-01-02  1.0 1.0 0.0
2019-01-03  0.0 2.0 0.0
2019-01-04  0.0 1.0 1.0
2019-01-05  0.0 1.0 1.0
2019-01-06  0.0 2.0 0.0
2019-01-07  0.0 2.0 0.0
```