# Pandas Rolling value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I am looking for a way in pandas to return the specific `value_counts()` over a rolling time window. I found the following question ([pandas `value_counts` on a rolling time window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466560/pandas-value-counts-on-a-rolling-time-window)), but it's not quite what I would like.

If I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     symbol
0     apple
1     apple
2     apple
3     apple
4  cucumber
5  cucumber
6  cucumber
```

I would like to have this output:

```
     symbol  counts
0     apple       1
1     apple       2
2     apple       3
3     apple       4
4  cucumber       1
5  cucumber       2
6  cucumber       3
```

So far I'm using a for loop, which works, but is very time-consuming for bigger DataFrames:

```
for index in df.index:
    symbol = df.at[index,'symbol']
    df.at[index,'counts'] = df['symbol'].value_counts()[symbol]
```

Does somebody have a better and faster solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` "symbol" and use `cumcount` to get the numbering (have to add 1 since `cumcount` starts from 0):

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby('symbol').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
     symbol  counts
0     apple       1
1     apple       2
2     apple       3
3     apple       4
4  cucumber       1
5  cucumber       2
6  cucumber       3
```